# Can't deploy *.war to Glassfish 4

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, ejb

I have an Bean interface, AbstractBean (implements Bean) and SpecificBean (extends AbstractBean). I want to inject SpecificBean by following code snippet:

```
@Stateless
@Specific
public class SpecificBean extends AbstractBean {..}

@Path("resource")
public class Service {
    @Inject
    @Specific
    private Bean bean;
}
```

When I trying to deploy this to glassfish, I see next error:

> An error has occurred Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [IterableProvider>] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 2 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.JerseyClassAnalyzer(@Named ClassAnalyzer, IterableProvider>)].

If delete all annotations (expected @Path) application deploys without any errors.

Comment: If you use CDI, it should work with no problems. If not, replace `@Inject` by `@EJB("<beanName>")` where `"<beanName>"` is the name of the specific bean implementation.

Comment: When I trying to deploy this to glassfish, I see next error: 

Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [Ref<ContainerRequest>] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.UriRoutingContext(Ref<ContainerRequest>, ProcessingProviders)].

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza yes, I use CDI, but receive above error when deploy war to glassfish 4.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the whole message error.

Comment: Is `@Specific` actually a `Qualifier`? From the error log you see that only the `@Default` qualifier is applied to the injection point.

Comment: @rubenlop88, yes it is actually a Qualifier: 
`@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface Specific {
}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Removed jersey from the dependencies list in maven pom.xml (jersey already contains in glassfish 4) and it deploys ok now.

Answer (score 2):

I found this questions with similar problem and just want to add my "2 cents". In my case, I was using Jersey 2.0 with Jackson in order to transform JSON to objects  and object to JSON from my rest interfaces. This means that I had to register `JacksonFeature` on `ResourceConfig` like this:

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.message.GZipEncoder;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

public class JacksonRestConfiguration extends ResourceConfig {

public JacksonRestConfiguration() {
    register( new GZipEncoder() );
    register( JacksonFeature.class );
}
```

I also disabled Moxy on my Application extension:

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.CommonProperties;

@ApplicationPath("services")
public class RestApplication extends Application implements Feature {

    public boolean configure( final FeatureContext context ) {
        String postfix = '.' + context.getConfiguration().getRuntimeType().name().toLowerCase();
        context.property( CommonProperties.MOXY_JSON_FEATURE_DISABLE + postfix, true );    
        return true;
    }
}
```

Both classes above required me to keep jersey as `provided` in my `pom.xml` in order to generate the war file correctly:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.13</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.13</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I had precisely the same problem except without Maven, but it sounds like changing the scope to "provided" equates to including the JAR at compile time but not when deploying. Doing so through my tool (Ant) fixed it for me. Thank you for your 2 cents!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some steps which helped me to solve this problem:

1. Open a command window (preferably as an administrator). 
   Click on Start -> type cmd
   and press ENTER.
2. Go to the path where you have install GlassFish, for example:
   C:\AppServers\glassfish5\glassfish\bin.

   Run these commands:

   ```
   asadmin start-domain  
   asadmin set configs.config.server-config.cdi-service.enable-implicit-cdi=false
   ```
3. Restart GlassFish and try to deploy you application.

Thanks to Stuart Mcculloch for the support on this forum: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=490794&goto=1068764&#msg_1068764

> Exception Occurred :Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Injector with qualifiers @Default

Solve problem to deploy de aplicacion en GlassFish
[image]