# Sample simple web application with jersey 2 and cdi?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jersey

I read many tutorials but can't understand why cdi not working for me. My code you can see at [Can't deploy *.war to Glassfish 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19868843/cant-deploy-war-to-glassfish-4) and [Why CDI not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876703/why-cdi-not-working)

Jersey 2.4, Glassfish 4, Java EE 7

Can anybody show a sample please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [CDI webapp](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/examples/cdi-webapp) example available on GitHub. Examples are tested against the GF main development branch, see [latest nightly build](http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/glassfish/4.0.1/nightly/latest-glassfish.zip) of GF.

If you're interested there are also [CDI integration tests](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/tests/integration/cdi-test-webapp) that can be used to demostrate CDI + JAX-RS.